# 3 added and subtracted from one column while printing

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

So I had this question as homework where I am supposed to take a 2-D array input and then sort only the outer boundary and print the sorted array. I made the program and it works perfectly for 3*3 and 2*3 matrices but when I input this particular 4*4 array, two numbers get added/subtracted by 3.

[image]

somehow, the 4 and 11 appear instead of 7 and 8 and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I have the parts of code involving the sorting and arranging below:

```
int boundnum = (2 * m) + 2 * (n - 2);
    int bounds[] = new int[boundnum];

    i = 0;

    for(j = 0; j < m; j++, i++)
        bounds[i] = a[j][0];
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++, i++)
        bounds[i] = a[j][n - 1];
    for(j = 1; j < n - 1; j++, i++)
        bounds[i] = a[0][j];
    for(j = 1; j < n - 1; j++, i++)
        bounds[i] = a[m - 1][j];

    for(i = 0; i < boundnum; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < boundnum - 1; j++)
            if(bounds[j] > bounds[j+ 1])
            {
                int temp = bounds[j];
                bounds[j] = bounds[j + 1];
                bounds[j + 1] = temp;
            }

    i = 0;

    for(j = 0; j < n; j++, i++)
        a[0][j] = bounds[i];
    for(j = 1; j < m - 1; j++, i++)
        a[n - 1][j] = bounds[i];
    for(j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--, i++)
        a[m - 1][j] = bounds[i];
    for(j = m - 2; j > 0; j--, i++)
        a[j][0] = bounds[i];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use a debugger, its what they are there for...

Comment: I think that you should get some practice with debuging your own code. try with different test examples at the begining and check every single loop one by one. there is no shortcuts in writng code, every element should be tested and understood by yourself : ). Of course you can try the debuger and make some breakpoints. just keep going

Comment: @Dominik I can usually debug all my code and my friends' too but this time I can't figure out what's going wrong. That is the only reason I'd put it up here :)

Comment: Also, what stumps me is that I have nothing that even remotely modifies the values other than a loop for bubble sort (not looking for efficiency right now)

Comment: @redFIVE I did try that, and it didn't solve my problem. As I said, I wouldn't post it here unless I absolutely had to.

Comment: for sure its not about modyfing your values, its wrong assumption. just you are  taking random values from the inside : )
edit: ohhh there aren't 4 and 11... sry

Comment: it actually works well if I try smaller arrays like 3x3 or 2x3

Comment: well but its still a problem with taking bounds of your array. for sure your code doesn't add anything- instead u are just taking 4 and 11 two times in one of the loops. for smaller array it can work even if there is a bug. A bug does not appear in every test case. otherwise it won't be a bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100178/discussion-between-dominik-and-namsnath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed the loop conditions that were wrong. At some places, the rows and columns were interchanged. The correct solution would be this:

```
    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++, j++) //fill elements in row 0
        a[0][i] = bounds[j];
    for(i = 1; i < m - 1; i++, j++) //fill elements in column (n-1) from row 1 to m-2
        a[i][n - 1] = bounds[j];
    for(i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--, j++) //fill row m-1, columns n-2 to 1
        a[m - 1][i] = bounds[j];
    for(i = m - 2; i >= 1; i--, j++) //row m-2 to 1, column 0
        a[i][0] = bounds[j];
```